# C++ unicode strings - the basic_strings know nothing about Unicode?

Tags: c++, unicode, unicode-string

I see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) that the C++ standard library now has typedefs of `std::basic_string` like `u8string` and `u16string`, but I don't see any member functions or algorithms that know much of anything about Unicode.

Let's say I want to iterate over the "grapheme clusters" in a string stored as UTF-8. These are the things that humans view as "characters", even though they may be multiple bytes or even multiple 32bit code units (like emoji flags ). Am I right that `std::u8string` has nothing for that and I need to use a library like ICU?

It appears the `substr` member function would split a UTF-8 or UTF-16 character in half, so again I need to use ICU or something to make sure I don't do that.

Correct?

Comment: C++ is very good at dealing with bytes. UTF8 stores Unicode characters in bytes. IMHO [this](http://utf8everywhere.org) is the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I right that `std::u8string` has nothing for that and I need to use a library like ICU?
>
> It appears the `substr` member function would split a UTF-8 or UTF-16 character in half, so again I need to use ICU or something to make sure I don't do that.

Yes, you are correct, on both counts.  The standard C++ library has no concept of Unicode codepoints/graphemes, only of encoded codeunits stored in individual `char`/`wchar_t`/`char16_t`/`char32_t` elements of strings.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, yes. C++ unicode support is still very basic.